Is it true that $\sin^2((2n+1) \pi x) \geq c$ occurs often (in precise sense)?
Fix $x \in [0, 1/2]$ and consider the function $f(n, x) = \sin^2((2n +1) \pi x)$.
Based on plotting, it seems like the following is true

For every $x \in (0, 1/2)$, there exists $c \in (0, 1]$ and a positive integer $N$ such that for every $k \geq 0$, there exists an integer $m \in [kN, kN + N)$ such that $f(m, x) \geq c$.

In other words, we can partition the integers $\mathbb{N} = \cup_{k \geq 0} I_k$ where $I_k = [k N, kN + N) \cap \mathbb{N}$ and on each interval there is some $m \in I_k$ for which the function $f$ is bounded away from $0$ uniformly.
I tried to prove or disprove this claim using the fact that $\sin^2((2n+1) \pi x) = \sin^2(\pi \{(2n+1) x\})$ where $\{t\}$ denotes the fractional part of $t$, but I failed to make much progress.
Is this claim true?

The claim is true. Indeed, consider the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of points of the unit circle $$\mathbb T=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2:u^2+v^2=1\}$$ such that $z_n=(\cos (2n+1)\pi x,\sin (2n+1)\pi x)$ for each natural $n$. Then $z_{n+1}$ is the point $z_{n}$ rotated counterclockwise around the origin $(0,0)$ by the angle $\alpha=2\pi x$.
Suppose first that $x$ is rational. Then $x=\frac{M}{N}$ for some integers $M$ and $N$. Since $x\in \left(0,\frac 12\right)$, $N\ge 3$. It is easy to show that the points of sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are exactly the vertices of the regular $N$-gon inscribed into the circle $\mathbb T$. Since $N\ge 3$, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $f(n,x)>0$. Put $c=f(n,x)$. Then $f(n+mN,x)=f(n,x)=c$ for each nonnegative integer $m$.
Suppose now that $x$ is irrational. Pick any $c<1$. Since the function $\sin \pi t$ is continuous and $\sin\frac{\pi}2=1$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\sin^2\pi t>c$ for each real $t$ such that $\left|t-\frac 12\right|\le \frac{\varepsilon}2$. Pick any natural $P\ge\frac 1{\varepsilon}$. Among $P+1$ numbers $\{\{2px\}:p=0,1,\dots, P\}$ from the segment $[0,1]$ there exist two distinct numbers $\{2px\}$ and $\{2p'x\}$ such that $0<\{2p'x\}-\{2px\}\le \frac{1}{P}$. Put $M=|p'-p|$ and $\delta=\{2p'x\}-\{2px\}$. Pick any natural $Q\ge\frac 1{\delta}$. Then among $Q+1$ numbers $\{\{(2(n+qM)+1)x\}:q=0,1,\dots, Q\}$ there exists a number $\{(2(n+qM)+1)x\}$ such that $\left|\{(2(n+q)+1)x\}-\frac 12\right|\le\frac \delta{2}\le \frac{\varepsilon}2$, so $$f(n+qM,x)=\sin^2\pi (2(n+qM)+1)x=\sin^2\pi \{(2(n+qM)+1)x\}>c.$$

Perhaps I didn't understand, but in the irrational case, in order to conclude your lower bound, don't you need to show that $t = {(2(n+pM) + 1)x}$ satisfies $|t-1/2|\leq \epsilon/2$? Also, I am a little confused, are your two choices of the natural $P$ the same?

@DrewBrady Thanks for the attention and sorry for the wrong text, I fixed it.

Context
Your question is very similar to this one: Sine function dense in $[-1,1]$, about the density of the sequence $sin(n)$.
The idea of the proof is to prove that $\mathbb{Z}+\pi \mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, which is a classic exercise in group theory.
This immediately shows that for values of $\pi x$ that are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independant of $\pi$, then, you have $\overline{sin^2((2n+1)\pi x)} = [0, 1]$.
Solution to the problem
If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then write $x = \frac{p}{q}$ with $p \in 
 \mathbb{N}^\star$ and $q\in\mathbb{N}^\star$. It follows that
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(nq, x) = \sin^2\left((2 q + 1) \pi \frac{p}{q}\right) = \sin^2\left(\pi\frac{p}{q}\right) = c > 0$$
If $x \not\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\pi x$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independant of $\pi$, and we can apply the aforementionned result, so $\overline{sin^2((2n+1)\pi x)} = [0, 1]$.
For instance, choose $c = \frac{1}{2}$, the result proves that there exists a subsequence $(\phi_n)_\mathbb{N}$ s. t. $sin^2((2\phi_n+1)\pi x) \to 1$, giving that $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n > n_0, sin^2((2\phi_n+1)\pi x) > 1 - \varepsilon$.
Choosing $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, this yields $\forall n > n_0, sin^2((2\phi_n+1)\pi x) > c$.
In conclusion, your claim is true.

Of course, this does little to solve my problem.

I've added details about the specifics of your problem

Your proof in the irrational case doesn’t help. It just says there’s a subsequence which is bounded from zero. It doesn’t say anything about how regular that subsequence is.

Completely missed the part about the regularity, my bad
